# Outlook conditional formatting of meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, conditional-formatting, meeting-request

I'm trying to highlight accepted and rejected meeting requests using conditional formatting. I'd like to make rejected show in a red font and accepted in green.
Can this be done with only conditional formatting or are rules required?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create a conditional formatting rule to achieve it.

[Automatically change incoming message colors and fonts based on sender, subject, or recipients](https://superuser.com/questions/1482057/outlook-conditional-formatting-of-meeting)

Comment: Hi Kelvin - I've managed to get a green colour for an acceptance, but I can't make a red colour for Declined. Is there a way to differentiate these? I've tried using the 'Forms', but this lumps accepted, declined and tentative into the one rule, even if they're separate.